Chapters with the same number but the reference go to the same image
I have two chapters with the same numbering, one in English and the other in Spanish. For example, both versions have a Table 2.1, but when I click on the Table 2.1 reference in the Spanish version, it redirects me to the English Table 2.1 instead. I've tried changing the labels, but the issue still persists. I have \selectlanguage{spanish},\addtocounter{chapter}{-5}, and \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla, english]{babel}
How can I resolve this? Thank you in advance!
